# Pegar ID do banco para carregar no select do HTML

Tags: php, sql

Como posso fazer para pegar ID do banco para carregar no select do HTML

Minha função assim:

```
public function ComboBox($sql, $idcampo, $selected)
{
     $cn = conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
     echo "<select name='" . $idcampo . "'>";
     $selec = "";
     while ($row = $cn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         if ($row[1] == $selected) {
             $selec = " selected";
         } else {
             $selec = "";
         }
         echo "<option value='" . $row[1] . "'" . $selec . ">" . $row[2] . "</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
 }
```

Ao ser chamada a função e passar o $sql, o $idcampo e o status (selecionada ou não).

Chamo ela para gerar o select para selecionar o valor para fazer a inserção, 
Só que não sei como pegar o $idcampo na página de insert, 
pois ele precisaria carregar todos $id's do banco para povoar o select no HTML.

Na chamada: `<?php echo $objct->ComboBox('select id, nome from cliente', $objcli->getIdcli(), 0); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez seja a questão não esteja bem elaborada, pois não entendo completamente qual o problema, mas o que entendo dos teus parâmetros é

```
$sql - SQL que vai retornar os resultados para preencher o <select> com valores
$idcampo - O nome do campo a dar ao <select> (pode ser qualquer coisa!)
$selected - O valor que deve ficar seleccionado no render
```

Neste momento tens `<?php echo $objct->ComboBox('select id, nome from cliente', $objcli->getIdcli(), 0); ?>`, ou seja, estás a passar o `ID` do objecto `$objcli` como o campo a ser usado, presumo que, actualmente, o HTML na página seja algo tipo `<select name="21">` (se for o 21 o valor retornado por `$objcli->getIdcli()`), e deveria ser algo tipo `<select name="id">`.

Para isso, a tua chamada na verdade teria de ser algo tipo `<?php echo $objcli->ComboBox('select id, nome from cliente', 'id', $objcli->getIdcli()); ?>`

Entretanto, o formulário onde esse `<select>` está, quando for submetido e quiseres saber qual o valor que foi escolhido, basta usares o `$_POST` (ou `$_GET`), por exemplo, se passaste `$idcampo` como `'id'`, seria `$_POST['id']` e a partir dai fazes o que precisares com esse valor.

//

### PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` retorna um array com os nomes dos campos como indice.

```
// Exemplo
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [nome] => Jão
)
```

Na tua funcao `ComboBox`, tu usas `$row[1]`, que na verdade deveria estar a dar erro, **Undefined index**. Provavelmente deverias usar `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, que te dá algo tipo

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [nome] => Jão
    [1] => Jão
)
```

E com este resultado, na função devias mudar o `$row[1]` para `$row[0]` e o `$row[2]` para `$row[1]` (visto que é um 0 based array).

O valor a passar em `$idcampo` pode ser só um string, podes por só `'id'` e deve funcionar correcto.

Comment: Seria o seguinte,
Essa função ao ser chamada gera um select onde ela é chamada, sendo passado os devidos parâmetros, o terceiro seria para edição não aplicado diretamente no insert.

Porém eu não sei como pegar o $idcampo do banco para que essa função funcione.
`$objcli->getIdcli()` ele não retorna o id com dados do banco.

Exemplo: para que fique o select gerado `<select>
  <option value="1">Jão</option>
  <option value="2">Fernado</option>
  <option value="3">Raimunod</option>
</select>`

Comment: Esse `$objcli` já tem de existir no código. Presumo que essa página seja um formulário para editar um registo? O `$objcli` seria, no meu entender, esse registo, e seria preenchido com um SQL SELECT anterior na página.

Comment: No caso esse formulário é para inserção.
Para edição eu já consigo pegar o id passado por $_GET['id'].
Agora no insert eu não estou conseguindo por não ter id passado.

Comment: Então, não precisas de ter o valor actualmente seleccionado. Precisas apenas dizer qual o campo para ser usado como `value` para as `<option>`

Comment: Sim, mais eu não sei como pegar o $idcampo do banco para jogar dentro porque `$objcli->getIdcli()` ele não retorna o id com dados do banco. 
Esse é meu problema.

Comment: Actualizei a resposta com mais alguma info. Eu acho que podes passar só `"id"` como o valor para `$idcampo`, visto que só é usado na linha `echo "<select name='" . $idcampo . "'>";`, não é usado para mais nada, logo nao deve afectar qual o campo de ID usado para o `<option value=...>`, isso é o `$row[1]`, que explico agora na resposta porque acho estar errado.